# ¿Se puede modificar una frase, o palabra de word con PHP 7?

Tags: php7

Estoy realizando un sistema web en donde me piden que genere unos formatos con base a una plantillas prediseñadas. El problema, es que algunas de estas plantillas, son en word. Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna librería como PHPSpreadSheet que permita acceder a un documento word y modificar algo en ese mismo documento con PHP 7 (que es el que uso)?

Comment: Hola, no se de acceso al documentos word desde php. Pero, es fácil desde word guardar como html y en ese momento tienes textos planos html más algunos estilos con los que puedes hacer lo que puedes hacer lo que necesites desde php.

Comment: ¿En serio? ¿Cómo se haría? ¿Y cómo se podría descargar de nuevo, pero como PDF?

Comment: En serio, abres el documento word, le das archivo->guardar como escoges el formato documento html y asignas la estensión al renombrar el archivo. Guardas y tienes todo listo (cuando yo lo hacía, hace mucho tiempo word creaba algún subdirectorio en el mismo lugar en el que incluía las hojas de estilo. No se como lo haga ahora pero no debe haber cambiado)

Comment: Bien. Ya lo he intentado. Se ve feísimo, pero creo que funcionará. Ahora, ¿Cómo lo modifico?

Comment: Y, buscaste dónde están las hojas de estilo, revisa el header del documento. Entra al chat de SOes y seguimos ahí

Comment: Ok. ¿Cómo incio ahora el chat?

Comment: [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: Agradecería mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola tengo que salir en este momento, pero estoy de vuelta en 30 minutos. Entra al chat con el enlace del comentario anterior. ahí suele haber alguien que ayude

Answer (score 1):

Ya que mencionas a PHPSpreadsheet existe una librería del mismo autor (autores) pero destinado a trabajar con documentos Word, es el PHPWord.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

En lo personal sólo trabajé con PHPSpreadSheet y era una maravilla como quizás ya lo sabes, creí que el proyecto estaba abandonado hace años pero por lo visto no, cuestión de echarle un ojo y ver qué tal.

Para futuras referencias, también del mismo autor (autores) hay librerías para leer y crear archivos de PowerPoint, Visio y Project.

Comment: Esa sólo permite crear los documentos, no modificarlos.